# Fusion table - Custom properties json

Tags: google-fusion-tables

While creating a table or adding a column in my fusion table, there is an option "Custom properties JSON". I need help with the properties that can be changed with this json. Also, what format should the json have.

Thanks,

Comment: I actually want to add some color to my table and its data. Came across a couple of websites having coloring in their fusion tables- https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=1296453#rows:id=1   

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1-GccVjOLNKXkW7gyVNEFZhkOz3E-fmjfXT_w77M#chartnew:id=5

Comment: Updated link available?